# How to trigger a jenkins build with a Web Activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: jenkins, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to trigger a jenkins job using the API. I got the set the token, got to run it successfully in the browser and got a json output from the API call using:

`https://<MY_JENKINS_ADDRESS>/job/path/job_name/api/json/build?token=my_token`

I tried to use this call in a `POST` or `GET` web activity in Azure Data Factory but I'm getting this error:

```
Error calling the endpoint '<MY_JENKINS_ADDRESS>'. Response status code: 'NA - Unknown'. More details: Exception message: 'NA - Unknown [ClientSideException] Invalid Url:https://<MY_JENKINS_ADDRESS>/job/path/job_name/api/json/build?token=my_token. Please verify Url or integration runtime is valid and retry. Localhost URLs are allowed only with SelfHosted Integration Runtime'.
Request didn't reach the server from the client. This could happen because of an underlying issue such as network connectivity, a DNS failure, a server certificate validation or a timeout.
```

It is clear data factory can't access the url. How can I solve this issue? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I am assumimg that the <[https://<MY_JENKINS_ADDRESS](https://%3CMY_JENKINS_ADDRESS)/job/path/job_name/api/json/build?token=my_token>> is not a publically  available and if that the case you should know that with ADF you can only access public facing urls . What that means is that If there anything whch is running on my local network or say on my laptop , ADF will be not abe able to access that .